# Не ровня или неровня?

Tags: словообразование

Изначально я думал, что "не ровня" нужно писать раздельно только в тех случаях, когда речь идет про противопоставление, но в национальном корпусе русского языка куча примеров использования как первого, так и второго вариантов без каких-либо дополнительных условий.

1. Андрей ему не ровня.
2. Маша неровня Ларисе.
3. Они тебе совсем не ровня.
4. Он мне неровня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неровня - это значит кто-то ставит одного выше, а другого ниже другого,

Достоевский любил слово неровня:

> Я представляла себе этого человека ― неровню; я старалась угадать весь мучительный смысл этого слова: «неровня».

Неровня - это по праву, по чему-то ментальному, отрицание равенства равенства между людьми в духовном, моральном смысле.

> ― Эй, Прошка! не бери греха на душу: загубишь девку понапрасну, а себе не сыщешь ни пользы, ни радости. Неровня она тебе и не пара.  А. В. Амфитеатров.

Неровня - неподходящая, то из чего не сделаешь целое, с кем не по пути. Ну и патетика "не бери греха на душу..загубишь девку(душу) понапрасну". Отрицание какой либо выгоды...

Неровня - качественное неравенство:

> Ты бы меня тогда заставлял на четвереньках ходить, когда я был неровня тебе… Горький

А не ровня - это не равный в чем-то, где-то, по статусу, по умению, сравнение внешнего навыков, социального положения, а не внутренних человеческих качеств:

> ― Что мне, говорит, до твоего барина за дело? Он, говорит, мне не ровня: что мне с ним знакомиться? Поди, говорит, отваливай. ― Вот еще! ― ворчал Иван Савич, ― не ровня. Как же бы это устроить? Ах, славно! выдумал! Часто ли она бывает тут у окна? Гончаров.

*Не ровня, но сойдемся*:

> Вы пророк! О, мы сойдемся, Карамазов. Знаете, меня всего более восхищает, что вы со мной совершенно как с ровней. А мы не ровня, нет, не ровня, вы выше! Но мы сойдемся.

И вот *не ровня и не пара*:

> Напротив того, Зина держала себя так, как будто жила в облаках, а не в городе Мордасове. Была она этим людям как-то не пара, не ровня и, может быть, сама не замечая того, вела себя перед ними невыносимо надменно.

Лживая духовность Зины: "она держала себя = вела с расчетом и показывала окружающим что они ней не ровня". Не ровня - утилитарное. Не пара - в смысле не друзья, товарищи, вела себя с другими не как с равными, а не как в прошлом примере, когда речь шла о духовном вечном единении - замужестве.

Касательно ваших фраз - они слишком примитивны, чтобы понять как писать, хотя, наверное, лучше в таких фразах писать "не ровня" и не выпендриваться. То есть, если не знаешь, то "не ровня", а неровня - это когда связано с какими-то смыслами, а не с утилитаризмом или решаемым делом, а не когда "не равенство" в чем-то не является преградой для взаимодействия - "не ровня, но сойдемся".

Comment: В Нацкорусе выбор делается по контексту.  Если же это тест, то раздельное написание  в 3-м варианте, а остальные лучше писать слитно. НЕРОВНЯ, -и; м. и ж. Разг. Человек, неравный другому в каком-л. отношении (в умственном, моральном, социальном и т.п.). Он ей н. Любить неровню.

Comment: @Sharon 3-м это каком?  (в умственном, моральном, социальном и т.п.). - ну в нацкорпусе есть примеры которые опровергают это. Знакомства я съ нимь не водилъ, потому не ровня онъ мнѣ былъ и по годамъ, и по званію, и по образованію, а по дѣламъ - вот пожалуйста, социальное "по образованию", "по званию". Или вот еще: ― Как будто боярская дочь, да еще княжна Долгорукова, мне не ровня? Социальное положение - это "не ровня"

Comment: Они тебе совсем не ровня. Здесь усиление отрицания.  А в остальных случаях неважно в каком, главное что неровня.  Это же тест., здесь формальное решение. А вот отрицать заранее лучше не надо,, а то составители вас не оценят правильно.

Comment: @Sharon про раздельное я написал - не знаешь, пиши раздельно. Но про "формальное решение" - неровня - это вообще неформальное употребление, нельзя придумать правило, когда его прямо нужно употреблять, потому что если правило будет, то тогда будет писаться "не ровня". Я не согласен с тем, что весь язык можно формализовать. И это как раз такой пример, когда стандартизация не работает.

Comment: В формате тестов и решения формальны, большего от вас не ждут)

Comment: @Sharon то-то и оно, что человеческая речь - это не те слова, которые ждут. И раз ответы формальные, то писать надо четко "не ровня" не нарушая формальные нормы правил. Тем более что там одни имена даны, как вообще можно определить, что имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Буратино, спасибо за ответ и комментарии. Многое стало понятно.

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо за обсуждение. Почерпнул для себя новое.